# Como crio umas variavel para exibir mensagem de erro ou sucesso?

Tags: php

Como faço para exibir mensagem de erro em uma variável, por exemplo:
Executou o código tudo certo ai tem q aparecer a primeira mensagem:

```
        if($count==1)
        {
        // PRIMEIRA MENSAGEM

            $change_profile_msg[] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
            <strong>Sucesso!</strong> Perfil atualizado.
            </div>";            
        }
        else
        {
            $change_profile_msg[] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>&times;</button>
            <strong>Erro ao atualizar!</strong> Não foi possível atualizar o usuario.
            </div>";
        }
```

Ai no local que quero exibir a mensagem:

```
$main_content .= ' EXIBIR MENSAGEM AQUI DENTRO APOS TUDO OCORRER BEM OU MAL NO SUBMIT DO FORMULARIO ';
```

Seria algo do tipo:

```
foreach($change_profile_msgs $change_profile_msg) {
      $main_content .= ''.$change_profile_msg;
}
```

Só que ai vai exibir mensagem de erro falando algo do tipo *Undefined variavel* e **só vai mostrar a mensagem quando executar o submit, como faço para ocultar esse foreach até executar o formulario e retornar algo para exibir a mensagem** ?

Comment: Pode verificar o tipo de requisição, se um GET o usuário está abriando a tela de cadastro, se for POST ele está gravando as informações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie uma sessão.

Use o seguinte javascript:

```
//Função responsável por exibir ou ocutar o feedback mensage
function showAlert(type, message) {
    if (message !== '') {
        if (type === '') {
            type = 'success';
        }
        $('#alert').removeClass();
        $('#alert').addClass('alert-' + type).html(message).slideDown();
        setTimeout("closeAlert()", 15000); // 15 segundos
    }
}

//chama a função para fechar o alerta quando clicado.
$(function () {
    $('#alert').click(function () {
        closeAlert();
    });
});
//
function closeAlert() {
    $('#alert').slideUp();
    $('#alert').removeClass();
}
```

Na sua página php no head onde :

```
       <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                showAlert('Error', 'Bem vindo, visitante');
            };

        </script>
```

Na sua página php no body:

```
<div id="alert"></div>
```

O CSS:

```
#alert {
    display: none;/* O alerta deve iniciar oculto */
    min-width: 300px;
    height: auto;
/*    border-radius:10px;*/
    font-family:Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*position: fixed;*/
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -160px;
    z-index: 999999;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.alert-error {
    background:#FF5252;
    border:1px solid #f5aca6;

}

.alert-success {
    background: #0f9d58;
    border:1px solid #2ecc71;
}
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]